# How to properly setup permissions to start Postgres replication?

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to [follow the Debezium tutorial for Postgres](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-permissions) and set up a replication user. I am creating the replication user as follows:

```
CREATE ROLE replication_role WITH REPLICATION LOGIN;

CREATE USER debezium WITH PASSWORD 'my-secret-pw';

GRANT replication_role TO debezium;

CREATE ROLE replication_group WITH LOGIN;

GRANT replication_group TO postgres;

GRANT replication_group TO debezium;

ALTER TABLE person OWNER TO replication_group;
```

and it sets up the replication user as follows:

```
                                                     List of roles
     Role name     |                         Attributes                         |              Member of               
-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 debezium          |                                                            | {replication_role,replication_group}
 postgres          | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {replication_group}
 replication_group |                                                            | {}
 replication_role  | Replication                                                | {}
```

When I try to start the Postgres source connector, I get the error as follows:

```
io.debezium.DebeziumException: Creation of replication slot failed
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: must be superuser or replication role to start walsender
```

How do I fix the permissions issue so that I can start replicating from Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER USER debezium REPLICATION;
```

Answer (score 1):

The replication attribute is not inherited.  That attribute must be set directly on the role which will use it.  You say you are following the tutorial, but as far as I can tell you are not.  You seem to be confusing the permissions/attributes needed to create publications, with the ones needed to stream the publications.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I agree that I am finding the tutorial a little bit confusing. What do I need to change in my SQL to get this to work?

Comment: I guess `CREATE USER debezium WITH PASSWORD 'my-secret-pw' REPLICATION;`